# How to open a INI file with Notepad.exe in [Run] section?

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup, how can i open an INI file with Notepad.exe using the [Run] section?

This is what i have, but its getting "%1 is not a valid win32 program"...

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\data.ini"; Description: "Check here see data."; Flags: postinstall runascurrentuser skipifsilent unchecked;
```

What i need is to open that file in user notepad after finishing the installation, if the user checked that checkbox.

Maybe its easier to do with code, but i am not sure how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Filename: "notepad";  Parameters: {app}\data.ini; Description: "Check here see data."; Flags: postinstall runascurrentuser skipifsilent unchecked;
```